# why is Python requests not working as intended

Tags: python, api, http, python-requests, rpc

I want to get some info from an JSON RPC API endpoint.
the equivalent curl command is this:

```
curl 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com' -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1,
    "method": "getTokenAccountBalance",
    "params": [
      "FYj69uxq52dee8AyZbRyNgkGbhJdrPT6eqMhosJwaTXB"
    ]
  }
'
```

it works and response is:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"context":{"apiVersion":"1.13.5","slot":176510490},"value":{"amount":"68662508944","decimals":5,"uiAmount":686625.08944,"uiAmountString":"686625.08944"}},"id":1}
```

but when I want to make a call in my python script:

```
headers={'Content-type': 'application/json'}
            data1 =  {
              "jsonrpc": "2.0",
              "id": 1,
              "method": "getTokenAccountBalance",
              "params": [
                "FYj69uxq52dee8AyZbRyNgkGbhJdrPT6eqMhosJwaTXB",
              ]
            }
response = requests.post('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com',headers=headers,data=data1) 
print(response.text)
```

I get this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki because the first one is actual JSON (no trailing commas) while the second is a Python data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you should be using `json` argument of the `requests.post` function, not the `data` argument.

This is how you fix it:

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
data1 = {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "method": "getTokenAccountBalance",
  "params": [
    "FYj69uxq52dee8AyZbRyNgkGbhJdrPT6eqMhosJwaTXB",
  ]
}

response = requests.post('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 
                         headers=headers, 
                         json=data1)
print(response.text)
```

Notice the `json` argument of the `requests.post`.

Comment: Thanks alot!! thought it will infer the type from header argument and didn't you can specifically choose json, I'm new to the requests library sorry